# Prove that a set R of real numbers is well ordered iff there is no infinite decreasing sequence of numbers in R

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, well-orders

## Problem

> Prove that a set $R$ of real numbers is well ordered iff there is no infinite decreasing sequence of numbers $R$. In other words, there is no set of numbers $r_i \in R$ such that
>
> $r_0 > r_1 > r_2 > \cdots$

(*Note*: the textbook says, verbatim, "iff there is no infinite decreasing sequence of numbers $R$", but I'm assuming there is an "in" missing, and it should be "iff there is no infinite decreasing sequence of numbers **in** $R$".)

## Solution

To prove that a set $R$ of real numbers is well ordered iff (if and only if) there is no infinite decreasing sequence of numbers in $R$, it's necessary to prove both directions of the "if and only if":

1) If a set $R$ of real numbers is well ordered, then there is no infinite decreasing sequence of numbers in $R$:

*Proof*. If a set $R$ of real numbers is well ordered, then every non-empty subset of $R$ has a minimum element.

Therefore, there is no infinite decreasing sequence of numbers in $R$, because that would be a subset without a minimum element.

2) If there is no infinite decreasing sequence of numbers in a set $R$ of real numbers, then $R$ is well ordered:

*Proof*. If there is no infinite decreasing sequence of numbers in $R$, then every sequence of numbers in $R$ has a smallest element. Therefore, $R$ is well ordered.

Therefore, $R$ is well ordered iff there is no infinite decreasing
sequence of numbers $R$.

Is this proof complete?

Comment: You're giving the same argument twice. It's more subtle in the other direction. You're basically claiming it without proof for 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One direction is easy: a (strictly) decreasing sequence $(x_n)$ defines a subset $A=\{x_n: n \in \Bbb N\}$ that has no minimum (because if $x_n \in A$ were a minimum, $x_{n+1} < x_n$ contradicting the minimality).

The other direction needs a bit more care:
If we have any non-empty set $A$ without a minimum, then use recursion (plus dependent choice): define $x_0 \in A$ as you want (it's non-empty after all). Note that having defined $x_n$ for some $n$, by assumption it is not $\min(A)$ so there is some $a \in A$ such that $a < x_n$, and then define $x_{n+1} = a$ and we continue the recursion. This defines a strictly decreasing sequence in $A$ (hence in $\Bbb R$) and we have a contradiction. So we have a well-order.

Note that we only use we're in  a linear order and nothing specific about $\Bbb R$  e.g. This fact holds in all linear orders: well order iff no decreasing sequence (if you believe in dependent choice).

Comment: Thank you. Can you please check if the following proof for direction 2 works better?

_Proof_. Assume that R is not well ordered. So, R has some non-empty subset S that has no smallest element. Then, an infinite decreasing sequence $a_1,a_2,...,a_n,...$ can be built as follows: choose a member of S as $a_1$. Since $a_1$ is not a minimum of S, there is some element in S smaller than $a_1$. So, we can choose $a_2 < a_1$. In the same way, we can choose an $a_3 < a_2$. Continuing this way, an infinite decreasing sequence $a_1 > a_2 > ... > a_n > ...$ can be constructed, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @favq that’s essentially what I did. If you have shown a recursion theorem in your course, you should explicitly appeal to that. “ continuing this way” can be more formalised and your course might demand a more formal approach.